# How may i use File.exists in Datatable.select expression

Tags: c#

I have a datatable which contain a column Path of file. Now i want to filter file Path is exist or not.

```
DataTable.Select(File.Exists(ColumnsName))
```

Would you please help me how may i filter.

Comment: You search it in a specific column?

Comment: Yes, one column of that table contains file path

Answer (score 0):

You can filter datatable by file path column by checking existence using File.Exists

```
var result = dataTable.AsEnumerable().Where(r=>File.Exists(r.Field<string>("Path"));
```

Answer (score 0):

DataSets are a pretty old concept in .NET so to use LINQ you need a bit of extra syntax:

```
dataTable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(row => File.Exists(row.Field<String>(columnName)))
```

This will return an `IEnumerable<Boolean>` that determines if the files exist.